# Extended @FacesComponent as composite interface componentType renders nothing

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I'm trying to extend JSF's component class (let it be one of `h:panelGroup`) and render it via composite component:

Step 1:

```
@FacesComponent(value="customPanel")
public class CustomPanel extends HtmlPanelGroup { // or UIPanel
}
```

Step 2:

```
<!-- INTERFACE -->
<composite:interface componentType="customPanel"/>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<composite:implementation>
  <h:outputText value="Some text:"/>
  <composite:insertChildren/>
</composite:implementation>
```

And step 3:

```
<xyz:panel>Hello world!</xyz:panel>
```

shows nothing. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backing component of the composite component must implement [`NamingContainer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) and the `getFamily()` must return `javax.faces.NamingContainer`. See also description of the `componentType` attribute in the [`<composite:interface>` tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/interface.html).

```
@FacesComponent(value="customPanel")
public class CustomPanel extends HtmlPanelGroup implements NamingContainer {

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

}
```

You can also choose to extend [`UINamingContainer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) instead, so that you can omit the `getFamily()`.

#### See also:

- [Composite component wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info)