# Primefaces composite component not rendering

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I'm trying to build in a composite component in JSF with PrimeFaces.

in src/main/webapp/resources/components I have a component called editableLabel.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<composite:interface componentType="editableLabel">
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="editMode" required="false" default="#{false}" type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:panelGroup id="editableLabelComponent">

        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{cc.attrs.editMode}">
            <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>

            <p:commandButton value="Update" actionListener="#{cc.update}"/>

            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" actionListener="#{cc.cancel}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>


        <p:outputLabel id="display" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" rendered="#{!cc.attrs.editMode}">
            <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{cc.toggleEditMode}" update="editableLabelComponent"/>
        </p:outputLabel>
    </h:panelGroup>
</composite:implementation>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Backed by a FacesComponent called EditableLabel.java

```
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by labraham on 1/14/16.
 */
@FacesComponent(value = "editableLabel")
public class EditableLabel extends UIComponentBase implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 108467781935083432L;
  private String oldValue = "";


  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  public EditableLabel() {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public String getFamily() {
    return "foo.bar.components";
  }

  /**
   *
   */
  public void update() {
    toggleEditMode();
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    this.oldValue = (String) getValueExpression("value").getValue(context.getELContext());
  }

  /**
   *
   */
  public void cancel() {
    toggleEditMode();
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ValueExpression valueExpression = getValueExpression("value");
    valueExpression.setValue(context.getELContext(), this.oldValue);
  }

  /**
   *
   */
  public void toggleEditMode() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Boolean editModeValue = (Boolean) getValueExpression("editMode").getValue(context.getELContext());
    ValueExpression editModeVe = getValueExpression("editMode");
    editModeVe.setValue(context.getELContext(), String.valueOf(!editModeValue));
  }
}
```

Yet when I try to stick it in an another file like so

foo.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:comp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
>
```

...

```
<h3>Test</h3>
<comp:editableLabel value="#{foobean.testValue}"/>
```

It doesn't render. It tried removing the rendered attributes from the component (as well as editmode composite:attribute) and I've verified that it's looking for editableLabel.xhtml in the right place. foobean.testValue is just a string with a default value of "test value" and the appropriate getter and setter.

Why might PrimeFaces refuse to render this composite component?

Edit: I've also tried replacing the primefaces components in the composite component with their JSF equivalents and that didn't work. And I tried removing the ajax calls to see if maybe it was some issue with that. It wasn't.

Edit 2: Its an issue the my FacesComponent but I don't know what. Removing the component type attribute got it to render at least.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out thanks to BalusC's answer to [Extended @FacesComponent as composite interface componentType renders nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038047/jsf-extending-standard-components-via-composite-interface)

I needed to implement NamingContainer and getFamily() in EditableLabel.java